# Less, css . изменить одно свойство класса

Tags: css, вёрстка, less

Имеется класс Less, допустим, который из DIVа делат круг:

```
  .round {
  width: @diameter;
  height: @diameter;
  background: floralwhite;
  -moz-border-radius: @diameter/2;
  -webkit-border-radius: @diameter/2;
  border-radius: @diameter/2;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

И вот вопрос, как сделать два круга только с разными размерами, без создания новго класса, хотелось бы менять только width и height, но я пока не могу придумать как - подскажите.

Answer (score 4):

Оставляешь в этом классе только основу, а размеры помещаешь в другой класс.

```css
.round {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: silver; /* поменял цвет, чтобы их видно было */
}

.small {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.big {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.other {
  width: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<span class="round small"></span>
<span class="round big"></span>
<span class="round other"></span>
```

> кучу классов плодить тоже не охото. Нельзя ли именно путем изменения 1й строки, в которой указан размер, все это производить?

Less компилируется в css. Да, в less'е можно сделать функцию, принимающую радиус. Но на html-элемент ты всё равно должен повесить существующий класс, а не вызов функции. Т. е. ты должен сделать те же два класса с разными размерами и в каждом из них вызвать функцию, которая добавит соответствующие свойства этим классам. Если хочешь, можешь пойти таким путём, но я не вижу в нём преимуществ.

```
.round(@size) {
  display: inline-block;
  width: @size;
  height: @size;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: silver; /* поменял цвет, чтобы их видно было */
}
```

Comment: кучу классов плодить тоже не охото. Нельзя ли именно путем изменения 1й строки, в которой указан размер, все это производить?

Comment: @Vitaly, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

В css появились переменные: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

```css
.round {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: silver; /* поменял цвет, чтобы их видно было */
  width: var(--width);
  --height: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
}
```

```html
<span class="round" style="--width: 10px;"></span>
<span class="round" style="--width: 100px;"></span>
<span class="round" style="--width: 10px; --height: 100px;"></span>
```